# crear funcion que a partir de paramentros devuelva letras con sus valores

Tags: javascript, programación-funcional

Holaa, me podrían ayudar con este ejercicio? Estoy aprendiendo Javascript y directamente no entiendo lo que tengo que hacer ni cómo hacerlo

Guerra de palabras Utils: var abc = {a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4,e:5,f:6,g:7,h:8,i:9,j:10,k:11,l:12,m:13,n:14,o:15,p:16,q:17,r:18,s:19,t:20,u:21,v:22,w:23,x:24,y:25,z:26}

Debés crear una función llamada warWords que reciba dos palabras como parámetro y devuelva la ganadora según la suma del valor de sus letras (dado por su posición en el abecedario).

Ejemplo: warWord(“hola”, “chau”) debe retornar “hola” (36 > 33) warWord(“love”, “friendship”) debe retornar “friendship”

Comment: Si no has intentado nada, difícilmente te ayuden

Comment: Y porque no entiendo cómo hacerlo y eso es lo que estoy preguntando, si vas a comentar obviedades segui jugando a la play

Comment: Lo leí, pero lo comenté de todas formas porque las preguntas frecuentemente terminan cerradas o perdidas entre el resto por ese motivo. Por tanto es mejor idea pedir ayuda en un servidor de programación de discord, a un amigo, un profesor o buscar ejemplos.

Comment: El problema es claro pero es necesario que nos digas que investigastes y que no entendes

Answer (score 1):

Simplemete convierte la palabra a array con un split, recorrer cada letra con un reduce y vas sumando la propiedad del abc en la letra, y finalmente solo comparas, se puede reducir el código pero eso te lo dejo a ti

```js
var abc = {a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4,e:5,f:6,g:7,h:8,i:9,j:10,k:11,l:12,m:13,n:14,o:15,p:16,q:17,r:18,s:19,t:20,u:21,v:22,w:23,x:24,y:25,z:26}
function warWord(w1, w2) {
  let uno = w1.split("").reduce((a, c) => (a += parseFloat(abc[c])), 0);
  let dos = w2.split("").reduce((a, c) => (a += parseFloat(abc[c])), 0);
  if (uno > dos) {
return { texto: w1, comparación: uno + ">" + dos };
  } else {
return {
  texto: w2,
  comparación: dos + ">" + uno,
};
  }
}

console.log(warWord("love", "friendship"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Te piden una funcion que reciba como parametros las palabras a comparar esta tendra que obtener un valor numerico de cada palabra de acuerdo a la estructura del objeto abc
Para ello podemos obtener  un array cuyos elementos sean las letras de las palabras para asi poder recorrer ese array vinculandolo a los valores de las claves del objeto
Te dejo comentados los console.log() para que sigas al codigo

```js
const abc = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5, f: 6, g: 7, h: 8, i: 9, j: 10, k: 11, l: 12, m: 13, n: 14, o: 15, p: 16, q: 17, r: 18, s: 19, t: 20, u: 21, v: 22, w: 23, x: 24, y: 25, z: 26 }

warWord('hola', 'chauchauchau');
warWord('kilokilokilo', 'chauchauchau');
warWord('hola', 'chau') ;
warWord('love', 'friendship') 
function warWord(word1, word2) {
    let valorWord1 = valor(word1);
    let valorWord2 = valor(word2)
    if (valorWord1 > valorWord2) {
        console.log('-gano-->', word1, valorWord1);
    }
    else if (valorWord2 > valorWord1) {
        console.log('gano --->', word2, valorWord2)
    }
    else { console.log('empate') }


}

function valor(word) {
   // console.log(word);
    //obtenemos un array cuyos elementos son las letras de las palabras
    const valoresWord = Object.values(word);
   // console.log(valoresWord)
    // recorremos el array que contiene a las letras de la palabra
    // para acceder a los valores de las claves del objeto
    let valores = valoresWord.map(
        val => {
           // console.log(abc[val]);
            let a = abc[val]; return a
        }
    )
    //  sumamos esos valores
    let suma = 0;
    valores.forEach(function (numero) {
        suma += numero;
    });
   // console.log(suma);
    return suma
}
```

> Entendiendo lo anterior si usamos reduce() con un  valor Inicial 0 al
> llamar a reduce,  el valorAnterior será igual al   valorInicial y
> valorActual será igual al primer elemento del array.
> Podemos así simplificar mucho el código con el acumulador que se
> aplica a cada elemento del array obtenido mediante Object.values() con unacódigo más limpio y mucho más fácil de leer si se entiende lo que hace reduce().[Teoria sobre reduce()](https://medium.com/@xadrijo/un-vistazo-a-la-funci%C3%B3n-reduce-en-javascript-f4459bc4e3aa)

```js
const initialValue = 0;
const abc = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5, f: 6, g: 7, h: 8, i: 9, j: 10, k: 11, l: 12, m: 13, n: 14, o: 15, p: 16, q: 17, r: 18, s: 19, t: 20, u: 21, v: 22, w: 23, x: 24, y: 25, z: 26 }

warWord('hola', 'chau');
warWord('kilokilokilo', 'chauchauchau');
warWord('empate', 'empate');

function warWord(word1, word2) {
    let valorWord1 = valor(word1);
    let valorWord2 = valor(word2)
    if (valorWord1 > valorWord2) {
        console.log('-gano-->', word1, valorWord1);
    }
    else if (valorWord2 > valorWord1) {
        console.log('gano --->', word2, valorWord2)
    }
    else { console.log('empate') }


}

function valor(word) {
    const valoresWord = Object.values(word);
    const sum=valoresWord.reduce(
  (pre, current) =>pre + abc[current],
  initialValue
);

   return sum

}
```